# How do I build a Node.JS app to handle real-time data on a Laravel project?

Tags: node.js, laravel

I want to build my own Pusher (https://pusher.com). I can (and have) just use the Pusher service but I don't want to be governed by the rules of their API and I want the experience of building my own product such as this.

Can anyone point me in the correct direction to do so? I'm assuming Pusher uses Node JS to handle real-time data. How do I work Laravel and Node together to handle real-time data from a DBMS such as MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

Socket io may help allows you to push data based on events without using an https request.